# vuetify.js v-select minimum height limitation?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

As you can see from below, I am trying to reduce the height of a `v-select` element, but it appears there's a limit to the minimum height I can set. i.e. after `height = 40`, further reducing the height doesn't seem to work anymore. Is there anyway to surround this limit so I can make this element smaller? I need this because I need to fit it into a relative small div. Thanks in advance -

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    years: [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.3.7/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.3.7/vuetify.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
<v-app>
  <v-layout row>
      <v-select
        label="height=80"
        outline
        height="80"
        :items="years">
      </v-select>
      <v-select
        label="height=60"
        outline
        height="60"
        :items="years">
      </v-select>
      <v-select
        label="height=40"
        outline
        height="40"
        :items="years">
        </v-select>
      <v-select
        label="height=20"
        outline
        height="20"
        :items="years">
      </v-select>
  </v-layout>
</v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: the `min-height` is `56px`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim it's good to know that. I need it to be shorter than 56px. Not sure if that's possible -

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `min-height` of `v-select` component is `56px` which is defined by the following CSS rule :

```
     .v-text-field--box .v-input__slot, .v-text-field--outline .v-input__slot{
       min-height:56px;
     }
```

let's override it for example by setting :

```
  .v-text-field--box .v-input__slot, .v-text-field--outline .v-input__slot{
   min-height: auto!important;
  }
```

but the result it's not perfect and the content is not aligned properly, to fix that we gonna add the following properties to the above rule :

```
  display: flex!important;
  align-items: center!important
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    years: [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
  }
})
```

```css
.v-text-field--box .v-input__slot,
.v-text-field--outline .v-input__slot {
  min-height: auto!important;
  display: flex!important;
  align-items: center!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.3.7/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.3.7/vuetify.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-layout row>
      <v-select label="height=80" outline height="80" :items="years">
      </v-select>
      <v-select label="height=60" outline height="60" :items="years">
      </v-select>
      <v-select label="height=40" outline height="40" :items="years">
      </v-select>
      <v-select label="height=20" outline height="20" :items="years">
      </v-select>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This looks promising. And pretty much what I am looking for, except the label and icon are misaligned. Do you know anyway to center align them vertically?

Comment: you're welcome, *it's hard to achieve that since we have font-size bigger that doesn't fit properly but i'm working on in this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RqLaar)

Comment: I am trying something like `.v-input__append-inner {
   margin-top: 0px;
 }` to move the icon up, which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Psidom i fixed that by adding some properties, i hope i could achieve that

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I am looking for. One more question though. When I apply these custom css in my component as *scoped*, will it affect all vuetify v-select element (application-wise)? or it will only affect this specific component.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem like these css style can be override locally for each component. But anyway, thanks for the excellent answer -

Comment: first css rule solution at my problem. thank you. i used like that                           
  <style lang="scss">
    @import '@core/scss/vue/libs/vue-select.scss';

    .v-text-field--box .v-input__slot, .v-text-field--outline .v-input__slot{
       min-height:56px;
     }
</style>

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with vuetify 1.5 and the accepted answer did not work for me, but this does, if you would like your height to be 32px for example:

```
.v-text-field.v-text-field--enclosed .v-text-field__details, 
.v-text-field.v-text-field--enclosed > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot {
        margin: 0;
        max-height: 32px;
        min-height: 32px !important;
       display: flex!important;
       align-items: center!important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best practice is to override default variables, check which one do you need (there are min-heights, padding, etc...) in API docs:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#sass-variables

For general info about Vuetify variables, see official docs:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/

Answer (score 0):

The given **solutions weren't working** for me... So I created one.

> This will reduce both the **select** and the **list items**

```
.v-select .v-input__control .v-input__slot .v-select__slot .v-select__selections {
  padding: 0 !important;
  min-height: 0 !important;
}

.v-select-list .v-list-item {
  min-height: 0 !important;
}

.v-select-list .v-list-item .v-list-item__content {
  padding: 4px 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dense prop to reduce the field height and lower max height of list items:

```
    <v-select
      :items="items"
      label="Outlined style"
      dense
      outlined
    ></v-select>
```