# How to resize the size of the Vuetify's v-select?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using VueJS 2 and Vuetify in my RTL project. I have the following code:

```
<v-card-title>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9" style="text-align: right; ">
      <div class="ml-1 inline">
        הצג
      </div>
      <v-select
        v-model="tableItemsPerPage"
        :items="itemsPerPageOptions"
        outlined
        single-line
        hide-details
        dense
        class="inline"
        style="width:90px;"
      ></v-select>
      <div class="mr-1 inline">
        פריטים
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3" style="text-align: left;">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="tableSearchText"
        class="shrink mx-4"
        append-icon="mdi-magnify"
        label="חיפוש"
        filled 
        rounded 
        dense 
        single-line 
        hide-details
      ></v-text-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</v-card-title>
```

Which creates the following UI:

[image]

I can't seem to figure how to resize the size of the `v-select`, since it looks a bit awkward. Tried the following solution: [vuetify.js v-select minimum height limitation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363333/vuetify-js-v-select-minimum-height-limitation), But it didn't work. How can I make it work?

**EDIT**: I'm after something like this:

[image]

The select box is a smaller and in the middle (from height aspect) from the search box. The desired font size of the keywords around the dropdown is:

```
  .v-card__subtitle, .v-card__text, .v-card__title {
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
```

Comment: you can use `min-width` property to set minimum width of `v-select` if you want to increase the size or you can use `sm` property for `v-col` like in this official doc https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/

Comment: @CreativeLearner Yes I want to decrease the size. how `v-col` helps here? Can't make it work for some reason.

Comment: You can set `max-width` property. It will help in decreasing the size.

Comment: @CreativeLearner Well, the height is actually the problem and not the width. Also, `v-select` does not have `max-width`.

Comment: max-width is a CSS property. You can apply a class in the element with this property.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class in existing inline class in your `v-select` element. You can use `max-width` or `min-width` property to align the width as per your requirement. Adding below snippet for your reference.

```
.inline {
  .select-box {
    max-width: 50px;
  }
}
```

**Working Demo :**

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app"
});
```

```css
.inline {
  .select-box {
    max-width: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.css"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="app">
  <v-card-title>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9" style="text-align: right;">
        <div class="ml-1 inline">
          הצג
        </div>
        <v-select
          v-model="tableItemsPerPage"
          :items="itemsPerPageOptions"
          outlined
          single-line
          hide-details
          dense
          class="inline select-box"
          style="width:90px;"></v-select>
        <div class="mr-1 inline">
          פריטים
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3" style="text-align: left;">
        <v-text-field
          v-model="tableSearchText"
          class="shrink mx-4"
          append-icon="mdi-magnify"
          label="חיפוש"
          filled 
          rounded 
          dense 
          single-line 
          hide-details></v-text-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-card-title>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it does not look like it works. I'm interested in making it smaller to fit the UI (not just the width). Also your snippet have errors and does not load.

Answer (score 1):

The Height property of `text fields`, `inputs`, `selects` are calculated from this SASS Variable:

```
$text-field-filled-full-width-outlined-slot-min-height
```

You can override it in order to change Select, text-field height or make them same height (by defualt, the should be the same)

Vuetify Docs: [How to override SASS Variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/)